# Posting to a php file via datatables and displaying result

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatable, datatables

Hi I'm new to datatables but I am finding them very interesting.

I have created this webpage using datatables:

http://www.berlitzmalta.com/ELTONTEST/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

This gathers data via php / mysql. Everything is OK however I am finding it difficult to do the following:

When the user clicks on View Abstract button I need the browser to open a new page or new tab and display the contents of data [5]. This is my code below:

```
<html> <head>   <meta charset="utf-8">  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="http://www.datatables.net/favicon.ico">    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0">

    <title>Department of English Linguistics Theses</title>     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../media/css/jquery.dataTables.css">    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/syntax/shCore.css">   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/demo.css">    <style type="text/css" class="init">

    </style>    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../media/js/jquery.js"></script>   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../resources/syntax/shCore.js"></script>  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../resources/demo.js"></script>   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">

$(document).ready(function() {  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {      //"ajax": "data/arrays.txt",        "columnDefs": [ {           "targets": -1,          "data": null,           "defaultContent": "<button>View Abstract</button>"      } ]     } );

$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {        var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();       $.post( "abstract.php", { name: data[5] } );        window.open ("abstract.php");       } ); } );

    </script> </head>

            <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Author</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Degree</th>
                        <th>Year</th>
                        <th>Abstract</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Author</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Degree</th>
                        <th>Year</th>
                        <th>Abstract</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>

                <tbody>

                <?php $con = mysql_connect('192.168.10.223',"user","passxxxx");


if (!$con)   {   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());   }

mysql_select_db("eltontest", $con);

$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM `Main`");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))   {

    echo "<tr>";   echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";     echo "<td>" . $row['AUTHOR'] . "</td>";   echo "<td>" . $row['TITLE'] . "</td>";   echo "<td>" . $row['DEGREE'] . "</td>";   echo "<td>" . $row['YEAR'] . "</td>";   echo "<td>" . $row['ABSTRACT'] . "</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
    }
     ?>


                    </tr>
                </tbody>            </table>

    </section> </body> </html>
```

As you can see I am using

```
$.post( "abstract.php", { name: data[5] } ); window.open ("abstract.php"); } );
```

to post in a php file called abstract.php file the contents of data[5] ... but I am getting a blank page !!

This is simply (for now) the content of my abstract.php file:

```
<?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>
```

What I want is that when the user clicks on View Abstract button the page submits 'Abstract' to the abstract.php file and displays the information ...

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are trying to POST data doesn't actually does what you wanted to achieve. It posts the data to abstract file in one thread and then as another thread it opens the abstract file with blank data.

So, Instead of

```
$.post( "abstract.php", { name: data[5] } ); window.open ("abstract.php"); } );
```

Just, do this:

```
window.open ("abstract.php?name="+data[5]);
```

This will open the abstract file and pass the data with query-string in get parameter.

And in PHP code instead of getting data by POST method

```
<?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>
```

Use this(GET):

```
<?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Syed Qarib - but no luck it's still giving me a blank page. I can see the contents of [name] in the URL but not on the page.

Comment: many thanks this is now working! However there will be quite some text in the [name] field and it's not nice to show all of this text in the URL. However, I think I can change this by calling data [0] which is the ID and then show the Abstract (data[5]) in php. Will get back with results ... Thanks once again

Comment: @elstiv: You are welcome.. and Yes that(id) approach will be good.. accept the answer so the thread will close..